# What I'm missing in this ChildAction or Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a child action in my controller that returns an image to an image tag in my view which calls the action via @Url.action. My problem is that when i remove the ChildActionOnly Attribute from the action the image renders but when i add it back it does not. I need the action to carry this attribute so it cannot be invoked directly. Below is my code.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
 public ActionResult  GetImage(int id)
        {
            var photo = _Db.Photozs.Single(p => p.PhotozId == id);
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Photo"+photo.Url);
            var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            return new FileStreamResult(fs, photo.ContentType);
        }
```

This is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<okay.models.photoz>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<<div class="container-fluid">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="pull-left span3">
            <img class="img-polaroid" src="@Url.Action("GetImage",new{id=item.PhotozId})"/>
            <div class="text-center">@item.Caption</div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Thanks guys in anticipation of your help

Comment: This is `View` or `Partial View` ? I think, `ChildActionOnly` should be used for `Partial View` only not for `View`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is **correct** but you are using `[ChildAction]` at wrong place just remove it.

[[ChildActionOnly]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute represents an attribute that is used to indicate that an action method should be called only as a child action.

You are not executing method as a child action so it doesn't execute after putting that attribute. Also A child action method renders inline HTML markup for part of a view instead of rendering a whole view.

- Any method that is marked with `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` can be called only with the `Html.Action()` or `Html.RenderAction()` HTML helper extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that when i remove the ChildActionOnly Attribute from
>   the action the image renders but when i add it back it does not

Use the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute only on actions that you are rendering with the `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction` helper. Those actions are never directly accessible from the client using a direct HTTP request. When you point the `src` property of an `<img>` tag to a server side endpoint, the browser is sending an HTTP request to this endpoint. And if the corresponding endpoint is decorated with `[ChildActionOnly]` it cannot be rendered to the client.

So you should remove this attribute from your controller action if you want this action to be directly accessible from the client using an HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. how do u suggest i re factor my code? i want to send the image to the view. how else do you think i can achieve this? of course with out the user able to directly invoke and get the image directly

Comment: Didn't you understand my answer? Remove the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute from your controller action if you intend to use it as target of an `<img>` tag. In case you didn't understand how child actions work I invite you to red the following blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Comment: i understood your answer quite alright. what i want to know is which other way can i get the image to the view without using a different action from the one that renders the view. Thanks once again

Comment: It looks like that's a dynamic image coming from your database or something. You should use a separate controller action to retrieve your image from the underlying data store and serve it to the view. There's no other way.

Comment: its an image in a folder but the path is saved in my database. save it to the view right?? ok guess i'll try putting in my ViewBag. Thanks